# How to upload a photo to Facebook using iOS FBDialogs?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

FBDialogs seems like a great way to share photos because it doesn't require user authentication and attributes to the app. The iOS 6 native share sheet looks great but some of our users only have facebook app installed and didn't configure Facebook in OS settings. I would like to use FBDialogs then fall back to share sheet. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do this seemingly easy job. All the *OpenGraphAction* functions require an URL to generate preview text. Is it possible to make it work like the iOS share sheet? I want to attach a local image, set initial text then let user type in whatever and press upload.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWihtParams..] which only accepts a link to an image.  If you want to share a local image with FBDialogs you must use [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAciton..] where the action object takes a reference to a local image. Keep in mind this API requires an open graph story to be configured in the Facebook developer portal so when the post shows up on Facebook it will be of the form "User verb a noun".

Take a look at the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls/) which discusses the different types of dialogs one can present in the native Facebook app.  The following example is copied from the Facebook docs

```
// only supports passing a single image

NSArray* images = @[@{@"url": [UIImage imageNamed:@"my-awesome-meal-photo.jpg"], @"user_generated" : @"true"}];    

id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
[action setObject:@"https://example.com/cooking-app/meal/Lamb-Vindaloo.html" forKey:@"meal"];
[action setObject:images forKey:@"image"];

[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                  actionType:@"fbsdktoolkit:cook"
                         previewPropertyName:@"meal"
                                     handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                         if(error) {
                                             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                         } else {
                                             NSLog(@"Success!");
                                         }
                                     }];
```